# How to revert the boolean value in razor view using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, razor-pages

I am just new to razor view. I am not able to change the boolean value from jquery. My code is :

```
@{ var edits = true;}
<button id="btnEditWorkPerformed" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-top: 10px;">Edit</button>
```

and in jquery i am trying it like :-

```
 $('#btnEditWorkPerformed').click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    @edits = !@edits
                    //alert('Lionel');
                    console.log(@edits)
                   });
```

while trying this in console i am getting an error in console

True is not defined

How can I revert the value of bool on button click?

Comment: Have you debugged the code to see what is the typeof and value of `@edits` first, before doing `@edits = !@edits`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor `@edits` is a server-side variable - you cannot change this client-side.

The solution is to convert it to a javascript variable so that it can be changed client-side.

```
<script>
    var edits = @(edits ? "true" : "false");
</script>
```

There are other ways, but note that `@edits.ToString()` returns `True`/`False` which is not the same as `true`/`false`, so it's not a case of `var edits = @edits`.

At this point you can then use `edits` as a javascript variable (ie without `@`):

```
event.preventDefault();
edits = !edits;
console.log(edits);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following code snippet:

```
 $('#btnEditWorkPerformed').click(function (event) {
                      event.preventDefault();
                      var edit =  (!"@edits");
                      console.log(edit);
               });
```

Without quotes, javascript will try to interpret True as a value/expression. There is no value True natively defined in javascript. It is "true" but javascript is case sensitive so it won't bind "True" to true.

var edit =  (!"@edits"); here the js variable `edit` assigned with the inverted value of razor variable `@edits`.